# How does one customize the appearance of jquery.perfect-scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, scrollbar

I am using [jquery.perfect-scrollbar](http://www.yuiazu.net/perfect-scrollbar/), which provides an excellent façsimile of the Mac OS X scrollbars of 10.8+ — and while [the author has claimed](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/issues/29#issuecomment-25367159) to facilitate a way by which it can be tricked out with CSS, I cannot figure out how to correctly implement any of the aesthetic augmentations he putatively supports.

**I am looking to activate the “visible rails” – to show the scrollbar *in sutu* regardless of the hover state – and to style it appropriately for its context on the page.**

Currently, it is invisible unless the hover state is active – in which case, this is what it looks like:

[image: Unstyled perfect-scrollbar screenshot sample]

This is the perfect-scrollbar source CSS, from [the commit](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/commit/2222ec5e9109b1f4c4864e65602ba20055f8afc1) to which [this particular issues’](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/issues/29) closed GitHub pull request alludes:

https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar/blob/2222ec5e9109b1f4c4864e65602ba20055f8afc1/src/perfect-scrollbar.css#L16

… I couldn’t find any calls to perfect-scrollbar’s jQuery API that facilitated this, nor any examples of how to approach styling it with CSS.

If anyone has any actual, non-speculative experience with this – or better yet a live working example at which I can be pointed – that would be especially helpful.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - what have you tried so far? Presumably you included the `perfect-scrollbar.css` file in your project... why not simply update that accordingly with the styles you want?  Or add styles of higher specificity to your own stylesheet that override the styles in `perfect-scrollbar.css`?  I was able to edit it easily in the Chrome Developer Tools inspector.

Comment: Also, no offense, but speaking like a 19th century nobleman does not really help people to understand your question.

Comment: I am indeed including the CSS – when I attempted to edit the `.ps-scrollbar-x-rail` class, I could see a screwed-up version of scrollbars’ background that flew off of the scroll area and shrank up erroneously when the bar was scrolled (either by grabbing it or using the mousewheel)… that’s why I particularly want to see a working styled example.

Comment: Could you set up a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that replicates your issue?  Preferably include the plugin CSS directly in the fiddle rather than linking to the external file as it will be easier for us to troubleshoot and propose solutions if we can modify that CSS.

Comment: you need to change the opacity and filter: alpha(opacity) and set rules without :hover and .hover [http://jsfiddle.net/jbxXN/](http://jsfiddle.net/jbxXN/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Abraham Uribe pointed out, you can achieve this by changing the opacity. If you only want to change a specific scroll bar without changing your CSS, you can use jQuery to make your y-rail visible:

```css
$("#YOU_DIV_ID").find(".ps-scrollbar-y-rail").css({"opacity":0.5});
```

or

```css
$("#YOU_DIV_ID").find(".ps-scrollbar-x-rail").css({"opacity":0.5});
```

for making your x-rail visible).

Comment: Thanks – that was/is absolutely the straightforward answer I was looking for. Salud!